# MomentJS - utcOffset() not applying offset?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have the following code:

```
const thresholdDate = "2020-02-12";
const value = "2020-02-12T01:00+02:00";

const valueUtcOffset = moment.parseZone(value).utcOffset();

const thresholdDateWithOffset = moment.utc(thresholdDate).utcOffset(valueUtcOffset);

console.log(moment(value).isBefore(thresholdDateWithOffset))
```

```js
const thresholdDate = "2020-02-12";
const value = "2020-02-12T01:00+02:00";

const valueUtcOffset = moment.parseZone(value).utcOffset();

const thresholdDateWithOffset = moment.utc(thresholdDate).utcOffset(valueUtcOffset);

console.log(moment(value).isBefore(thresholdDateWithOffset))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

The result of `valueUtcOffset` is `120`.

However, the `console.log()` returns `true` and i don't understand why.

`value` with the UTC offset is `2020-02-11 11PM`, whereas `thresholdDateWithOffset` should be `2020-02-11 10PM`.

So how come it says that `value` is before `thresholdDateWithOffset`?

Comment: `thresholdDateWithOffset` will not be 2020-02-11 10PM, it's actually midnight. Checkout my answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption here is wrong:

> `value` with the UTC offset is `2020-02-11 11PM`, whereas `thresholdDateWithOffset` should be `2020-02-11 10PM`.

`thresholdDateWithOffset` will actually be midnight utc, while `value` is 11 pm the day before. When you put `moment.utc("2020-02-12")` you are creating midnight in utc. When you apply the offset `moment.utc("2020-02-12").utcOffset(120)` it will still be midnight in utc, but represented as `"2020-02-12T02:00+02:00"`. You're just changing the offset the time appears as, you're not really changing the time. The real time used when comparing times remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of your snippet is correct.
You take timezone which is UTC+2 ( + 120 )

you ask `moment` to give you a date `const thresholdDateWithOffset = moment.utc(thresholdDate).utcOffset(valueUtcOffset);` on that timezone.

```
const thresholdDateWithOffset = moment.utc(thresholdDate).utcOffset(valueUtcOffset); //"2020-02-12T02:00+02:00"
```

then you check if  `"2020-02-12T01:00+02:00"` is before `"2020-02-12T02:00+02:00"` and it answered true which is true

```
moment.utc("2020-02-12") => 2020-02-12T00:00+00:00
moment.utc("2020-02-12").utcOffset(120) => 2020-02-12T02:00+02:00



moment.utc("2020-02-12T00:00+02:00") => 2020-02-11T10:00+00:00
moment.utc("2020-02-12T00:00+02:00").utcOffset(120) => 2020-02-12T00:00+02:00
```

Comment: What i want is to convert `thresholdDate` to `value`'s timezone, sorry if it wasn't clear from the question. So if the timezone of `value` is `GMT+2`, it means that `thresholdDate` is now `2020-02-11 11PM`

Comment: When you type moment.utc("2020-02-12") it's like moment.utc("2020-02-12T00:00+00:00"). then moment.utc("2020-02-12T00:00+00:00").utcOffset(120) equals 2020-02-12T02:00+02:00